# How to copy all end files in a directory to another directory in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

How can I copy all of the files that are found in subfolders within one directory, to another directory? I am having trouble with this because some of the end files are in more folders  than others.

I know of people using find so you can find certain endings to file names like .txt, but my files have no file type

I currently have
cp -r cs/cs/201*sp/. all/

The problem is, I have two folders that contain files that need to be copied which are a subset of 201*sp/

Currently, it copies all of the right items that are not in those two folders, but then it copies those folders themselves, when I need it to just copy their contents.

Comment: You can pass the `-type f` flag to find (i.e. `find ./ -type f`) and it will find ONLY files...that being said, how comfortable are you with shell scripts as this could be attained with one?

Comment: I need to copy them though, not just find them. @txtechhelp

Comment: Which is why I asked if you were comfortable with shell scripts, mixing `find` with some other commands can yield you that result...if you're not comfortable with shell scripting then there might be other options

Comment: Ah okay, I'm just now learning them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264529/how-to-navigate-to-subdirectories-in-a-shell-script <- navigate subdirs via shell script (for a reference)

Answer (score 0):

> find cs/cs/201*sp/ -type f -exec cp {} all/ \;

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit your answer to explain how the command works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need is a way to look within a folder, and all subfolders of that folder, and copy any files found into a different "destination" folder, without creating any subfolders in the "destination" folder.

So if you have a fileset like this:

```
folderA/file1
folderA/subfolderC/file2
folderA/subfolderC/subD/file3
folderA/subfolderC/subE/file4
folderB/subfolderF/file5
folderB/subfolderG/subH/file6
folderB/subfolderG/subI/file7
```

And you are copying the files to the folder **`"../destfolder"`**. Then, after the files are copied, the **`"../destfolder"`** will contain:

```
../destfolder/file1
../destfolder/file2
../destfolder/file3
../destfolder/file4
../destfolder/file5
../destfolder/file6
../destfolder/file7
```

and **`"../destfolder"`** will contain ***none*** of the subfolders from **`"folderA"`** or **`"folderB"`**.

You do this by changing to the directory that you want to copy the files from, and then run this from the command prompt:

```
d="../destfolder";for f in $(find -type f -exec echo {} \;); do b=$(echo $f|sed -r 's!^.*/([^/]+)!\1!'); echo cp -p "$f" "$d/$b" ;done
```

Before you "run" this command, you will need to substitute your actual destination folder in place of **`"../destfolder"`**

This will display a list of **`cp`** commands, but will not actually copy any files. It should look like this:

```
cp -p folderA/file1 ../destfolder/file1
cp -p folderA/subfolderC/file2 ../destfolder/file2
cp -p folderA/subfolderC/subD/file3 ../destfolder/file3
cp -p folderA/subfolderC/subE/file4 ../destfolder/file4
cp -p folderB/subfolderF/file5 ../destfolder/file5
cp -p folderB/subfolderG/subH/file6 ../destfolder/file6
cp -p folderB/subfolderG/subI/file7 ../destfolder/file7
```

Once you are confident the correct files will be copied, you can run the command again, but remove **`"echo"`** from the part of the command that's like: **`"echo cp -p..."`**

So the command that will copy the files will look like:

```
d="../destfolder";for f in $(find -type f -exec echo {} \;); do b=$(echo $f|sed -r 's!^.*/([^/]+)!\1!'); cp -p "$f" "$d/$b" ;done
```

Remember that before you "run" this command, you will need to substitute your actual destination folder in place of **`"../destfolder"`**

If you want this as a shell script, it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

d="../destfolder"

for f in $(find -type f -exec echo {} \;); do 
    b=$(echo $f|sed -r 's!^.*/([^/]+)!\1!')
    echo cp -p "$f" "$d/$b"
done
```

If this is not exactly what you need, then let me know and I'll have another look at it.